# read date time column into pandas dataframe. retain seconds information in the dataframe

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, datetime, timestamp

My csv file.

```
   Timestamp
---------------------
1/4/2019  2:00:09 PM
1/4/2019  2:00:18 PM
```

I have a column date time information in a csv file . I want to read this as a timestamp column into a pandas dataframe. **I want to retain the seconds information.**

Effort 1:
I tried

```
def dateparse (timestamp):

    return pd.datetime.strptime(timestamp, '%m/%d/%Y %H:%M:%S ')

df = pd.read_csv('file_name.csv', parse_dates['Timestamp'],date_parser=dateparse)
```

Above rounds off the seconds to something like

```
1/4/2019  2:00:00
```

Effort 2:

I thought of reading the entire file using and later convert it into dataframe.

```
with open('file name.csv') as f:
    for line in f:
        print(line)
```

But again here seconds information is rounded off.

edit 1:

The seconds info is truncated when I open this csv file in editors like sublime.

Comment: So there are no seconds in source file? Then impossible read  it...

Comment: @vijju Did you try to see the `dtype` of the col when reading the csv file. If its not `datetime[ns]` try 
 `df['col1'] =  pd.to_datetime(df['col1'], format='%d%b%Y:%H:%M:%S.%f')`

Comment: @Sumanth : The problem is, as soon as I read the file into dataframe, the seconds are truncated. your suggested step can happen only after I read the file.
How is that helpful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For me working omit `date_parser=dateparse`:

```
import pandas as pd

temp=u"""Timestamp1
1/4/2019  2:00:09 PM
1/4/2019  2:00:18 PM"""
#after testing replace 'pd.compat.StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(temp), parse_dates=['Timestamp1'])

print (df)
           Timestamp1
0 2019-01-04 14:00:09
1 2019-01-04 14:00:18

print (df.dtypes)
Timestamp1    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

EDIT1:

Correct format of datetimes should be changed:

```
import pandas as pd

def dateparse (timestamp):

    return pd.datetime.strptime(timestamp, '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p')

temp=u"""Timestamp1
1/4/2019  2:00:09 AM
1/4/2019  2:00:09 PM
1/4/2019  2:00:18 PM"""
#after testing replace 'pd.compat.StringIO(temp)' to 'filename.csv'
df = pd.read_csv(pd.compat.StringIO(temp), parse_dates=['Timestamp1'],date_parser=dateparse)

print (df)
           Timestamp1
0 2019-01-04 02:00:09
1 2019-01-04 14:00:09
2 2019-01-04 14:00:18

print (df.dtypes)
Timestamp1    datetime64[ns]
dtype: object
```

EDIT2:

```
df = pd.read_csv('send1.csv', parse_dates=['Timestamp'])
print (df)
            Timestamp
0 2019-01-04 14:00:00
1 2019-01-04 14:00:00
2 2019-01-04 14:00:00
3 2019-01-04 14:00:00
4 2019-01-04 14:00:00
5 2019-01-04 14:00:00
```

Comment: This is not working. 
Result: 2019-01-04 14:00:00
I replaced pd.compat.StringIO(temp) with filename.csv

Comment: @vijju - yes, check edit. If no information about seconds is not possible read it. Or something missing?

Comment: There is seconds information . First bit of information at the start of question is csv file

Comment: ValueError: time data '1/4/2019 14:00' does not match format '%m/%d/%Y %I:%M:%S %p'

Comment: @vijju - is data file confidental? Is possible share it?

Comment: I cant share the file.  sorry  :)

Comment: @vijju - Sorry, I am really confused. In your last edit you write - `edit 1:

The seconds info is truncated when I open this csv file in editors like sublime.` - So it means there are no seconds information and after convert to datetimes seconds are `0`. So problem is there are no seconds like `09`, `18` or no seconds like `00` ?

Comment: Effort 1: using python code.  1/4/2019  2:00:09 PM  is converted to 
1/4/2019  2:00:00.

Edit 1: When I try to open the raw file in sublime editor, the seconds information is truncated. i. e I get   just  :  1/4/2019  2:00

Comment: @vijju - Is possible share only `Timestamp` column? Because no idea why not working, for me it working perfectly.

Comment: @vijju - one idea - is possible share first values of timestamp column with no parsing to datetime? `L = pd.read_csv('file_name.csv')['Timestamp'].tolist()[:20]` and `print (L)` ?

Comment: https://drive.google.com/open?id=1qoIUKtUqYvh2c3W_DF--c9PfAX1uuAdI

Please let me know if you can download

Comment: @vijju - downloaded.

Comment: @vijju - check last edit, do you expect something else?

Comment: yes. The seconds  info is rounded off . I want to retain seconds information.
I hope the file you downloaded had the seconds information.

Comment: I want 2019-01-04 14:00:00 instead of  2019-01-04 14:00:09, which is in my original csv file.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/187103/discussion-between-jezrael-and-vijju).